# Null Reference Exception from extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods, nullreferenceexception

I have an extension method called `ParseItemsToIntegers` which is an extension method of an array of strings, and I'm using it like any extension would be used.

```
var ids = ChkBoxSelected.ParseItemsToIntegers();
```

The behavior I've observed is that, if `ChkBoxSelected` is null, it will call the extension method without a problem, but then in side the extension method it throws a null reference exception on the null string array.

How was it able to resolve the extension method on the null?

Why did it not throw a null reference exception on `ChkBoxSelected` when I called the extension method?

Comment: Try { ... if (return == null) { return -1 } } Catch { return -1 }

Comment: No I get that Dieter B.  I curious as to why it doesn't throw the null reference at the top level.  How does it get into the extension method on a null object?

Comment: Because it searches for the extension method on the type, not the object itself.

Comment: Extension methods are really just static method calls. Whatever object you 'call them on' is just passed as the first argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the extension method `ChkBoxSelected.ParseItemsToIntegers()` is equivalent to calling it using regular static method syntax `ParseItemsToIntegers(ChkBoxSelected)`. The type of `ChkBoxSelected` is known at compile time, so the compiler can resolve the method.

The `NullReferenceException` is thrown inside the method it tries to use the `ChkBoxSelected`.

When calling an instance method, the `NullReferenceException` is thrown immediately because the CLR checks the actual type of the object to choose correct polymorphic call (even non-virtual methods are called like that).

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't throw a NRE because extension methods *aren't instance methods*, regardless of how much they *appear* to be instance methods.  As is made clear when you're defining the method, it's actually a static method.  A NRE isn't thrown when you pass a `null` value as the first argument to a static method, it just passes in a `null` value and that static method can do whatever it wants with it.

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods are just syntactic sugar for a more explicit `static` method call.

So your code which might *appear* to be (it's not)

```
null.ParseItemsToIntegers();
```

is really being called like

```
StaticClass.ParseItemsToIntegers(null);
```

The null reference is just a parameter, which is perfectly fine accepting null as a value (since it's a legal value for a reference type).  Somewhere inside your actual method, it's presumably expecting a non-null array, and that throws an NPE then.